# Replace content of property files when publishing application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, properties, weblogic12c

We have an .ear project with several dependent .jar projects and we are using Maven. Each project has its own property file, but the properties inside do not have specific values but placeholders, e.g.

```
database.url=${database.url}
```

The placeholder ${database.url} is replaced during Maven build process using the resources plugin. So for each stage (local, test, integration, production) we have a different Maven profile defining the filter, so if we build for the test stage we get something like

```
database.url=url.for.test.db
```

The application is running on WLS 12, and we want to deploy it on local WLS using the Eclipse server plugin (we are using Eclipse Kepler). However, when we add the application to the server in Eclipse and publish, it is not working since the placeholders in the property files are not replaced with specific values.

AFAIK, the content being deployed is located in the Eclipse workspace:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<ear-project-name>\beadep\<WLS domain name>\<ear-project-name>
```

Of course we could change the property files in that location, but whenever we publish in Eclipse, those changes are overwritten and we get again the original property file

```
database.url=${database.url}
```

which is useless when it is deployed to WLS.

Is there any mechanism or possibility to change the property files before they are deployed to WLS from Eclipse?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the solution I chose to solve this (I am not sure whether it is the best one, but at least it is working):

I added a new folder to the .ear project named "properties-local". This folder contains only those property files which are relevant for local deployment (without placeholders), e.g.

> database.url=url.for.local.db

Wihtin the properties of the Eclipse project, there is a section "Deployment Assembly". I added the new folder "properties-local" to the deploy path APP-INF/classes, so this is the place where they will appear in the .ear which is used for local deployment.

The maven-ear-plugin, which is responsible to build .ear files for remote stages, is not aware of the directory properties-local.

So the drawback of the solution is, there are now two folders with property files: one for local Eclipse deployment, one for .ear files which are deployed on remote servers.